# log file has different time than the phone's time and the android studio's logcat

Tags: file, logging, time, timezone, save

I'm trying to generate a log file with this code:

```
JLog.init(this)
.setDebug(true)
.writeToFile(guardarLog)
.setLogDir(getString(R.string.carpetaLog))
.setLogLevelsForFile(logLevels)
.setTimeFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
```

and the log file was created but the the date and time of every log is exactly 11 hours later than the moment of the log and the android studio shows the correct date and time (the date and time of the phone) what would be the problem?

Comment: i checked that the time zone is correct, put .setTimeFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a z") and the file writes the correct time zone